# How to install and run the examples of QtOpenCl, i.e. Qt in OpenCl?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, opencl

The thing is I have to run the OpenCl examples, as given here:http://labs.trolltech.com/blogs/2010/04/07/using-opencl-with-qt/.

The problem is that I have no clue where to start. I downloaded the source for QtOpenCl but it needs a valid OpenCl installation. I have Qt installed already.

How do I install OpenCl? I don't have a GPU at home unfortunately, and need to implement it on my CPU for now. I have to later give a presentation where I will be supplied a system with a GPU. How do I go about installing OpenCl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ATI Stream SDK contains a CPU OpenCL implementation that you can use:

http://ati.amd.com/technology/streamcomputing/sdkdwnld.html

Installing it will give you a working OpenCL CPU Implementation.